# Capturing digits in sentences unless specific words appear in it (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write regex (in Python) that finds lines of text which contain specific words and captures the first number that appears after the word. The digit matching is done to match different types of numbers with different thousand and decimal separators.

My issue is that I want to add a blacklist of words that if these words appear between the match word and number, it breaks the match and returns None instead.

Currently regex looks like this - match words are `car` and `price`. Let's assume a blacklisted word `insurance`.

`(?:car|price)[^\r\n]+?(\d{1,3}[\s\.]\d{3}[\.\,]?\d{0,2}|\d{3,6}[\.\,]?\d{0,2})`

```
"price is 161" -> 161
"car: 5512.16" -> 5512.16
"this car has two prices this year 1151 and last year 9912" -> 1151
"car price is 1992 insurance 90" -> 1992
"car ID is an invalid number 92.16.17" -> No match
"in this case the price of the car spans over
two lines of text 912" -> No match
"price of insurance 199.116,16" -> 119.116,16
```

The last is an example where I want no match. So essentially some way to add an option to blacklist words between `(?:car|price)<here>(\d{1,3}...`.

Here are the test sentences as a list for your convenience:

```
import re
pattern = r'(?:car|price)[^\r\n]+?(\d{1,3}[\s\.]\d{3}[\.\,]?\d{0,2}|\d{3,6}[\.\,]?\d{0,2})'
list_of_sentences = ["price is 161", "car: 5512.16", "this car has two prices this year 1151 and last year 9912", "car price is 1992 insurance 90", "car ID is an invalid number 92.16.17", "in this case the price of the car spans over\ntwo lines of text 912", "price of insurance 199.116,16"]
for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    print(re.findall(pattern, sentence))
```

Current output

```
['161']
['5512.16']
['1151']
['1992']
[]
[]
['199.116,16']
```

Desired output

```
['161']
['5512.16']
['1151']
['1992']
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: You can add negative lookahead to filter out undesired matches. Simplest one will be like this: `(?!\D*insurance)`. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/jCCnu0/1).

Comment: I tried negative lookaheads but was was missing the `\D*` part, so now it works. Thanks! Final solution ended being `(?!.*(?:black|listed|words|here))`

Comment: @qoob: the lookahead in your comment gets rid of ANY sentence containing the blacklisted words, including your 4th example! You should keep the '\D'.

Comment: @Swifty I just replaced the `\D` with  `.` as to capture digits as well, but apparently it does have some issues. There were situations where sentences would be `car 5 insurance price 1150`, and it would match the correct number (1150) but ignore the blacklist. https://regex101.com/r/SjXAnu/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to exclude matches of blacklisted words between to parts:

```
(?:car|price)(?:(?!insurance|other|black|listed|words)[^\r\n])+?(\d{1,3}[\s\.]\d{3}[\.\,]?\d{0,2}|\d{3,6}[\.\,]?\d{0,2})
```

It's the same regex as you used with changed pattern in-between two interesting us parts.

Here `(?:(?!insurance|other|black|listed|words)[^\r\n])+?` matches anything except blacklisted words and newlines. Negative lookahead here prevents including lsisted words into match, and since we have something required to match after it, this approach prevents matching of lines where any blacklisted word is present between word car (or price) and following number of your format.

Demo can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/ayjqmk/1).

Answer (score 0):

this is my Regex `(car|price)(?!\D*insurance).*?(?P<number>\b\d+.\d(?:,\d{3})*(?:.\d{1,2})?\b,*\d*)`.

and this is the result from your given *sentences*.

each array have 3 **object** for

- full text
- keyword
- number

i wish your job get done :)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JZZq47/5)

```
[
  [
    {
      "content": "price is 161",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "startPos": 1,
      "endPos": 13
    },
    {
      "content": "price",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 1,
      "startPos": 1,
      "endPos": 6
    },
    {
      "content": "161",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 2,
      "groupName": "number",
      "startPos": 10,
      "endPos": 13
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "content": "car: 5512.16",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "startPos": 23,
      "endPos": 35
    },
    {
      "content": "car",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 1,
      "startPos": 23,
      "endPos": 26
    },
    {
      "content": "5512.16",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 2,
      "groupName": "number",
      "startPos": 28,
      "endPos": 35
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "content": "car has two prices this year 1151",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "startPos": 54,
      "endPos": 87
    },
    {
      "content": "car",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 1,
      "startPos": 54,
      "endPos": 57
    },
    {
      "content": "1151",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 2,
      "groupName": "number",
      "startPos": 83,
      "endPos": 87
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "content": "car price is 1992",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "startPos": 117,
      "endPos": 134
    },
    {
      "content": "car",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 1,
      "startPos": 117,
      "endPos": 120
    },
    {
      "content": "1992",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 2,
      "groupName": "number",
      "startPos": 130,
      "endPos": 134
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question ???

Comment: @Swifty check that again :)
you must get *Group* **number**

Comment: You haven't try this regex in real code, have you?

Comment: @InSync no , whats wrong with that?

Comment: You should. `re` won't accept it and will raise an exception.

Comment: @RezaParsian, on the left pane of regex101 you can change language where your regex is expected to be used. It is there for a reason, and if you'll select Python there, you'll be shown an error too. Hint: named groups are denoted in similar but other way in Python.

Comment: And I double Swifty's question: how is it expected to help OP? Your regex still matches number in the last line, while provided in question expected output clearly asks not to.

Comment: @markalex you make it so hard, if you can use regex you should know with **P** after question mark this regex works fine like php or js. like this `(car|price).*?(?P<number>\b\d+.\d(?:,\d{3})*(?:.\d{1,2})?\b,*\d*)`. that's not regex problem.

Comment: @markalex edited. check it now, i think he need last line too.

Comment: @RezaParsian, while it might be or not be a common knowledge, I still find it strange to provide answer in unrelated regex flavor, when question is clearly marks what flavor is used. Especially without mentioning it in answer itself. It would be rather strange if I'll post answer using BRE, and expect OP to rewrite it themselves, don't you think?

Comment: Regarding update: please see last comment by OP under question itself. This approach will match lines with blacklisted words in some cases.

Comment: @markalex i check my regex with selected answer and it works fine with **1004** less steps, BTW tnx alot for everything.